# ¿Que tipo de estructura devuelve una consulta SQL?

Tags: javascript

Estoy utilizando un software industrial, basado en JavaScript, el cual debo hacer consultas a una base de datos SQL. Utilizando los snippets del propio software puedes construir una consulta por defecto para que no tengas que conocer exactamente su sintaxis, pero no logro terminar de entender como devuelve los datos la propia consulta en la variable results. El código del snippet es el siguiente;

```
export function Botón_4_OnTapped(item, x, y, modifiers, trigger) {
 (async function() {
  try{
    let connectionstring = "Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server; Server=DESKTOP-L7VRKM6\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=DBprueba;trusted_connection=yes;";
    let conn = await HMIRuntime.Database.CreateConnection(connectionstring);
    let query = "Select * from Recipe;";
    let results = await conn.Execute(query);
     if(results !== undefined && results !== null)
     {
       let statements = results.Results;
       for(let statement in statements)
       {
         let rows = statements[statement].Rows;
         for (let i in rows)
         {
           let row = rows[i];
           for(let key in row)
           {
             HMIRuntime.Trace(key+":"+row[key]);
           }
         }
       }
     }
     conn.Close();
   }
   catch(e)
   {
     let res = e.Results;
     for(let statement in res)
     {
       let errors = res[statement].Errors;
       for (let i in errors)
       {
          let detailed = errors[i];
          HMIRuntime.Trace("Errors state : "+detailed.State);
          HMIRuntime.Trace("Errors Message : "+detailed.Message);
       }
     }
   }
 })();
}
```

Si utilizo una herramienta disponible, Trace Viewer puedo capturar los mensajes que lanzas con la instrucción que se ve en el código HMIRuntime.Trace(string) y veo que me devuelve realmente la consulta que le he realizado; nombre columna: valor1, nombre columna: valor 2 etc.

¿Alguien podría resumirme que retorna la consulta? ¿Devuelve una tabla? ¿Un array de varias dimensiones? No lo tengo muy claro, además, uno de los problemas que encuentro es que no es posible saber los métodos o funciones que puedo utilizar en la sintaxis, no tiene opción de Intellisense o cosas por el estilo. El Software está muy muy verde...

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si pudieras compartir una captura de lo que te devuelve la consulta podríamos darte una respuesta más precisa

Comment: @alejandro00 te dejo una captura de la tabla y lo que veo en el Trace Viewer

Answer (score 0):

La especificación de lo que se devuelve lo tiene definido el software industrial que utilizas (podrías agregar el nombre en el titulo, descripcion o tag ya que podría ser de utilidad para alguien que haya trabajado con lo mismo). A ***mi entender*** te esta devolviendo un JSON con esta estructura:

```
{
Results: [
    Rows: {
         nombre,
         valor
        }
    ]
}
```